# Encoding Hebrew Data in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, encoding, hebrew

I am receiving data (text) on socket from a third party that needs to be encoded in Hebrew. A third party says:

> For the Hebrew letters encoding, whenever you find an ASCII code greater than 127, you need to subtract 128 and add `#05D0` to get the Unicode value of the Hebrew letter (for each char in a Hebrew field).

My question is, how can I read data character by character? There might be multi-byte characters involved in the text received from the third party. I tried reading data and getting the ASCII codes with the following.

```
Recv(iSocket,AppMsg,&iLen,0)
int a = 0;
for(int i=0;i<strlen(AppMsg);i++)
{
    a = (int)pTitlOfAnncmnt->sTitleOfAnncmnt[i];
    Log.info("%s|%s|%d|Ascii Value Of Char Is [%d] ",basename(__FILE__),__func__,__LINE__,a);
}
```

The problem is, I am getting the wrong ASCII values from reading character by character. It is the wrong approach here. How should I read data so that I am able to get Hebrew data?

Comment: Tell your customer that you want UTF-8, not some custom encoding.

Comment: Possible bug.  for loop should be written as `for(int i=0;i<iLen;i++)`

Answer (score 3):

> There might be multi-byte characters involved in the text received from the third party.

If the characters were multibyte, they would already be UTF-8 and you wouldn't need this conversion.

In any case, the description given by your customer precludes any multibyte encoding being used at the same time.

> I tried reading data and getting the ASCII codes with the following.
>
> [*casts `char` to `int`.*]

`char` may be (and often is) `signed`, so you won't see values greater than 127 at all. That cast may produce negative values instead.

Use a cast to `unsigned char` instead.